# How could I make multiple symbolic links for multiple directories, conveniently

Tags: bash, symlink, brace-expansion

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v122 -> /home/files/video122
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v123 -> /home/files/video123
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v124 -> /home/files/video124
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v125 -> /home/files/video125
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v126 -> /home/files/video126
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v127 -> /home/files/video127
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v128 -> /home/files/video128
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v129 -> /home/files/video129
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v130 -> /home/files/video130
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v131 -> /home/files/video131
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v132 -> /home/files/video132
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v133 -> /home/files/video133
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v134 -> /home/files/video134
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v135 -> /home/files/video135
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v136 -> /home/files/video136
lrwxrwxrwx  1 deploy users    20  1월 23 18:15 v137 -> /home/files/video137
```

These are symbolic links.
If new `video138 ~ video150` volumes are mounted, I have to make `links v138~v150` of that.
Could you imagine a bash magic? (I tried to use `brace expansion` but couldn't make it work.)
It would be much better if the magic script can create the symlinks automatically, with detecting the volumes' mount.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try a simple `for` loop

```
for Num in {138..150}; do
  ln -s "/home/files/video$Num" "v$Num"
done
```

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
alias zln='zmv -L'
zln -s '/home/files/video(*)' 'v$1'
```

or

```
zln -s '/home/files/video(<138-150>)' 'v$1'
```

Otherwise, with zsh or recent versions of bash or ksh93 supporting `{x..y}`, you could do:

```
vln() for i do
  ln -s "/home/files/video$i" "v$i"
done

vln {138..150}
```

Comment: Is this working with bash?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Oh right, I read too fast and completely missed the second part, sorry.